Почему не находит ndk в ubuntu?
Пробую собрать библиотеки из проекта Android Studio. Ndk скачан и находиться тут /home/madoka/Android/Sdk/ndk/27.0.12077973
В файле
bashrc записано:
export NDK_HOME=/home/madoka/Android/Sdk/ndk/27.0.12077973
export PATH=$PATH:$NDK_HOME

Но не хочет видеть ошибка: Error: NDK not found.

Возможно, не установлена переменная окружения $NDK_HOME или $PATH. Если команда echo $SDK_HOME или echo $PATH выведет "not found" - значит нужно установить ее. Возможно также, что какая-то несостыковка версий
